# Toggle Button values change when i open my spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, togglebutton

I have a macro enabled spreadsheet with a pivot table.

The main function is clicking on different toggle buttons that will affect two pie charts on the left side of the screen.  Each button brings up different information in the pie charts.

I can get it working perfectly, but every time i re-open the spreadsheet, the toggle button values change for all the buttons I have set up.

Has anyone encountered this before?  or is there something i can look for in my VBA that would cause this?

Thanks

Comment: What's your code? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Would you like that the Tougle Button itself to preserve its last values?

Comment: Yes FaneDuru, I would like to ensure that the toggle buttons (There's about 16 in the spreadsheet) preserve their name.

When I right click a toggle button and click properties, the top area (name) is something like "ToggleButton11".

When I open the spreadsheet again, it will change that value to "ToggleButton XX"  XX being a random number between 1 and 16.

The Macro that i have written is referencing these buttons by "ToggleButton XX", so when these value are changed, it grabs the wrong information for the pivot tables.

Comment: Try, please, change their name in something better helping you to identify them and also to oblige Excel to keep their names. Something like `tgButOpen` and their caption in a similar way: `Toogle Open`. I, all the time, proceed in this way and never had such a problem. Now I am using Office 2016 Profesional 64 bit.

Comment: If you temporary delete a standard allocated name, Excel will adapt the next logical name to all the rest of such buttons...

Comment: Can you send some feedback? Did changing of the controls name solved your problem?